# consuming coldfusion webservices

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to build a web service. Here is my code for a simple web service which returns a string. 
At the beginning i inserted some code from [ben nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/430-My-First-ColdFusion-Web-Service.htm.) 
 It refreshes the stubfile automatically because otherwise you get errors while passing parameters.

```
<cfcomponent 
    displayname="BaseWebService"
    output = "false"
    hint="This handles core web service features">


    <cffunction
        name="Init"
        access="public"
        returntype="any"
        output="false"
        hint="Returns an initialized web service instance.">

        <cfreturn THIS />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction
        name="RebuildStubFile"
        access="remote"
        returntype="void"
        output="false"
        hint="Rebuilds the WSDL file at the given url.">

        <cfargument name="Password" type="string" required="true" default="" />

        <cfif NOT Compare(ARGUMENTS.Password, "sweetlegs!")>
            <cfset CreateObject("java", "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory"
                    ).XmlRpcService.RefreshWebService(
                        GetPageContext().GetRequest().GetRequestUrl().Append("?wsdl").ToString()) />
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction 
        name="easyService"
        access="remote"
        returntype="any"
        output="false">

        <cfargument name="anyOutput" type="string" default="this and that" />
        <cfargument name="xtype" type="string" required="yes" default="1" />        

            <cfif Compare(xtype, "1") EQ 0>
                <cfset anyVar = "one" />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset anyVar = "two" />

            </cfif>
        <cfreturn anyVar>       
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here I am trying to invoke the webservice.

```
<cfinvoke
    webservice="https://[...]/Components/Webservice.cfc?wsdl"
    method="RebuildStubFile">

    <cfinvokeargument 
        name="Password" 
        value="sweetlegs!" />
</cfinvoke>
<cfinvoke
    webservice="[...]/Components/Webservice.cfc?wsdl"
    method="easyService"
    returnVariable="anyVar" >

    <cfinvokeargument
        name="xtype"
        value="2" 
        omit="true">
</cfinvoke>

<cfdump var="#anyVar#">
```

The first method of my web service component can be invoked but the second one always returns this error message:

```
coldfusion.xml.rpc.ServiceProxy$ServiceMethodNotFoundException: Web service operation     easyService with parameters {xtype={2}} cannot be found.
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:149)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2301)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.InvokeTag.doEndTag(InvokeTag.java:454)
```

If i type in the url of the webservice, by adding

> ?method=easyService&xtype=2

it returns the right value. but this is like passing values with a GET method.

i have been searching for hours and don't know where the problem occures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when using WebService call you need to specify all arguments and use omit="true" on the proper one (not on xtype).

```
<cfinvoke
    webservice="[...]/Components/Webservice.cfc?wsdl"
    method="easyService"
    returnVariable="anyVar" >

    <cfinvokeargument
        name="anyOutput"
        value=""
        omit="true">

    <cfinvokeargument
        name="xtype"
        value="2">
</cfinvoke>
```